# How to make bottom navigation bar opaque in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to make my top status bar transparent using below code, which make status bar transparent but also make bottom navigation bar transparent.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance

        //  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

        // w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        //  w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

    }
```

[image]

I want to make bottom navigation bar opaque like below.

[image]

I want to make only status bar transparent not bottom navigation bar. So please help me as i am new in android

Although it work nice in kitkat as below i want, but not above kitkat.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

or

```
window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int)

will work for API level 21+